# highcharts-ng addpoint each second

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I has a livedata spline (updated each second)
But i ll do the same thing with an angular app

(I want to do this : http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update
with highcharts-ng in my angularApp.)

without angular i has :

```
events: {
                load: function () {

                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function () {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // now
                            y = Math.random()*180;
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
                    }, 1000);
                }
            }
```

But with angular i try to code with $scope to do this... this do nothing :/

```
 var series = $scope.series[0];
 setInterval(function () {
        var x = (new Date()).getTime() // now
      var y = Math.random();
        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
    }, 1000); 
};
```

here a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/c58b1z6b/10/

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will be able to achieve the desired results with a small change adding $scope.$apply in your setInterval function:

```
     setInterval(function () {
        var x = (new Date()).getTime() // now
        var y = Math.random()*180;
        $scope.$apply(function() {
           //series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
           series.data.push(y);
        })
    }, 1000);
```

I have commented out the original call to addPoint() as the results were not quite what I expected...

Comment: Thanks for answer. This work but i have a last thing to fix.

Comment: Work on this : http://jsfiddle.net/c58b1z6b/44/  But this add a point without deleting the oldest :/ and i don t need to have all data. An idea to fix this ?

Comment: I answer for my own question if someone need, for delete the oldes point just use
    series.data.shift();